# Триггеры в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться, пока не очень соображаю в триггерах.

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert_user AFTER INSERT ON users 
       FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
          UPDATE users 
          SET 
          guid =  SUBSTR(hex(randomblob(32)), 1,8) || 
            '-' || SUBSTR(hex(randomblob(32)), 9,4) || 
            '-' || SUBSTR(hex(randomblob(32)), 13,4) || 
            '-' || SUBSTR(hex(randomblob(32)), 17,4) || 
            '-' || SUBSTR(hex(randomblob(32)), 21,12),
          fullname = ifnull(NEW.fullname, NEW.name),      
          created = NOW(),
          visited = NOW()
          WHERE id = OLD.id;
       END;
```

выдает ошибку

> 1363 - There is no OLD row in on
> INSERT trigger

если поменять `WHERE id = OLD.id;` на `WHERE id = NEW.id;`
пишет

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 13

что я делаю не так?

Comment: А то, что OLD бывает только в UPDATE-DELETE триггерах вас не смущает? ))

Даже если это схавается валидатором кода, могут быть неожиданности в ходе работы.

Comment: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=630

http://www.rldp.ru/mysql/mysqlpro/triggers.htm

Comment: Да, меня это тоже смущало, так в статье было написано, исправить на NEW догадался. И спасибо за ссылки!

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался, для выполнения команд через PHPMyAdmin нужно было дописать в начале DELIMITER $$